# Can I use an array as a config const in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I'd like to have the starting position of my agents configurable.  Within the Chapel code I have

```
var DOG_STARTING_POSITION: [1..0] int;
```

Then within the `.cfg` file I have

```
DOG_STARTING_POSITION=[25,25]
```

But this produces the error

```
error: type mismatch in assignment from string to int(64)
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712619/is-it-possible-to-declare-an-array-with-config - I saw you opened an issue for it - thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to declare an array with config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712619/is-it-possible-to-declare-an-array-with-config)

Answer (score 0):

> *Can I use an array as a config const in Chapel ?*

### No.

This was explained by @bencray already in 2017/12 that

> this is not yet supported in Chapel as of Chapel 1.16

### In the meantime, a common proxy-solution exists:

One may always arrange inputs to take place from a configuration file ( a common step in a such configurable, pipeline organised computation flows ), given the wish is to read the whole *configurable*-array content.

If the attempt above was actually a wish to use a form of configurable means of **indirect addressing**,
let's

```
// DOG_STARTING_POSITION     = [25, 25]
   DOG_STARTING_POSITION_ROW =  25
   DOG_STARTING_POSITION_COL =  25
```

---

```
// and the already compiled code may later freely reference the value by:

   DOG_STARTING_POSITION     = anArrayCONTENT[ DOG_STARTING_POSITION_ROW,
                                               DOG_STARTING_POSITION_COL
                                               ];
/* using the indirect-addressing,
         delivered as
                      config const ( i.e. as trivial int coordinates
                                          from outside
                                          the code-execution context
                                          )
                   as late as
                   at run-time
                   */
```